# IIS ap.net COM error iTunes

Tags: asp.net, iis, com, itunes

I'm trying to write an app based on my iTunes Library. I don't have any problem in dev environnement (iis or dev srver). But in prod i've got this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {DC0C2640-1415-4644-875C-6F4D769839BA} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Échec de l’exécution du serveur (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Of course i'm searching and searching......

i've tryed all solution founded :

i've got full right for this acount :

- Local service
- Network service
- User
- IIS_IUSR

on this file :

- iTunes.exe

on this folder :

- App/iTunes
- Music/iTunes
- wwwroot
- sysWOW64...Desktop

And also on dcomcnfg :

- MyComputer/SecurityCOM on acces activate and exec
- DCOM configuration/iTunes on acces activate exec and config

i've put in my webconfig

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

AppPool is on pipeline classic and i'm trying with all identity and also with 32b support enabled

..... No result

i become crazy with security stuff...

anyone have some ideas...?

thank a lot

Comment: iTunes is a client software and I don't believe Apple designs it for server scenarios. Even if it works in some cases, you should think that's coincidence. Why exactly do you want to achieve by using the iTunes library? There can be other options.

Comment: No it's a COM object inside .exe and .net create an interop object. That work well on Dev environment (iis Dev server), I'm sure it's only security stuff. I want read my library, and playlist, for streaming it on and out my network... And design my own player.